# Running a bash script as root on boot

Tags: debian, ip-address, shell-scripting, ifconfig, startup-scripts

i have a script that calculate an ip address (using gateway address) than change,

the script work when i launch it manually with sudo

```
sudo ./changework.sh
```

i want this script to run during bootup time

i

```
sudo cp changework.sh /etc/init.d/changework
sudo chmod+x /etc/init.d/changework
sudo update-rc.d changework defaults
```

but it does not work,

also i tested it
using

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then added

```
@reboot sleep 10 && /home/ubunu/changework.sh
```

it does not work either

**changework.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#set interface
interface="enp0s5"

#read current IP address on interface
current_ip=`ifconfig $interface 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $3}'|sed 's/Bcast://'`
IP=`cut -f1,2,3 -d"." <<< $current_ip`
lIP=`cut -f4 -d"." <<< $current_ip`
lIP=`expr $lIP - 34`
IP=$IP"."$lIP
#return default gateway
gateway=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
#check if IP is taken using ping
count=`ping -c 1 $IP | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }'`

if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
        #change IP if available
        ifconfig $interface down
        ifconfig $interface $IP up
        ifconfig $interface
        #change gateway
        ip route add default via $gateway
else
        #IP change not possible
        echo "IP not available"
fi
```

would any one please have a solution or a workaround and thanks for any help or suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up doing changing the content of rc.local, and like @user2563336 we don't need root access because login script have root access

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
writeinterfacefile()
{ 
cat << EOF > $1 
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
# The loopback network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address $2
#network 192.168.1.0
netmask $3
#broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway $4
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
EOF
#don't use any space before of after 'EOF' in the previous line
}
file="/etc/network/interfaces"
current_ip=`sudo ifconfig eth0 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $3}'|sed 's/Bcast://'`
IP=`cut -f1,2,3 -d"." <<< $current_ip`
lIP=`cut -f4 -d"." <<< $current_ip`
lIP=`expr $lIP - 36`
ip=$IP"."$lIP
mask=`sudo ifconfig eth0 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $4}'|sed 's/Mash://'`
mask=`cut -f2 -d":" <<< $mask`
gateway=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
#/bin/rm  $file
/bin/mv $file /etc/network/BAKinterfaces
/usr/bin/touch $file
writeinterfacefile $file $ip $mask $gateway
/etc/init.d/networking restart
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a jessie (or latter) i would suggest to follow [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux) nice guide, since the it uses systemd approach.

Comment: Consider also that cron usually uses **sh** as default shell and not **bash**.
To use bash you should put a `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the line before your cronjob

Comment: Is the cronjob actually executed?
Watch out for the /home/ubun**T**u/changework.sh typo ...

Comment: after sudo crontab -e,                         SHELL=/bin/bash @reboot sleep 10 && /home/ubunu/changework.sh, but still nothing

Comment: Have you checked if the script is actually executed?
Check in **/var/log/syslog**.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use sudo if you are already root. And the only way to execute a script at system startup is being root.
- Why all the copying the file into /etc/init.d? Copy it there once and keept it there.
  Then execute it from there. - Or go with a script being called from systemd as proposed by Sandro B.
- Don't use commands only. Always give the full path. Especially at bootup and in cronjobs. E.g.:
  ifconfig is /sbin/ifconfig
- You want to use "/bin/ip" instead of "ifconfig". The latter is outdated.
- Why don't you use /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/network/interfaces.d ? ([man interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/interfaces.5.html)) . Especially "pre-up" to make sure that the script is always executed before the interface is up.
- If I get your intention right you want to use a dhcp server in your network. What would happen if the first IP you give to your server is already in use?

Comment: the reason why i'm not using /etc/network/interfaces is that the ip should be calculated and and not fixed, really thanks for answering, i'm starting by changing command to full path ifconfig => /sbin/ifconfig , ping => /bin/ping , ip => /sbin/ip, and i will test it

Answer (score 0):

i changed my code

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/changework
#set interface
interface="eth1"

#read current IP address on interface
current_ip=`/sbin/ifconfig $interface 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $3}'|sed 's/Bcast://'`
IP=`cut -f1,2,3 -d"." <<< $current_ip`
lIP=`cut -f4 -d"." <<< $current_ip`
lIP=`expr $lIP - 34`
IP=$IP"."$lIP
#return default gateway
gateway=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
#check if IP is taken using ping
count=`/bin/ping -c 1 $IP | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }'`

if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
        #change IP if available
        /sbin/ifconfig $interface down
        /sbin/ifconfig $interface $IP up
        /sbin/ifconfig $interface
        #change gateway
        /bin/ip route add default via $gateway
else
        #IP change not possible
        echo "IP not available"
fi
```

then

> sudo crontab -e

and added

> SHELL=/bin/bash
>
> @reboot sleep 10 && /home/ubunu/changework.sh

but nothing
any help please