# Running script as user with root permissions

Tags: linux, root, startup, startup-scripts, linuxmint

Due to conflicting and constantly changing permissions on mounted drives (which cannot easily be solved due to the development structure of programs), there is a script that must be run with root permissions.

This can be done with `sudo /usr/serverm1/lsintd` and provides good results. However, we wish to run this script automatically on startup.

Running the script under our main user on startup results in a core dump due to insufficient  permissions. Therefore, we figured we could set it in crontab as `@reboot /usr/serverm1/lsintd` (as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/849248/running-a-bash-script-as-root-on-boot), however this runs it with settings and config from root (which is non existent).

**TLDR: How can we run the script exactly as it would run with the command `sudo /usr/serverm1/lsintd` on startup?**

I also tried applying `chmod u+x` to the binary, however this still resulted in a core dump as if run with regular perms (idea taken from [let a user run a script with root permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/75620/ubuntu-let-a-user-run-a-script-with-root-permissions)).

Side note: *I admit this is somewhat an XY problem, however due to the slow and poorly organized development structure of some of the other services on our server, we have no way of solving the root issues and must instead workaround with this.*

Comment: Is sudo configured to require a password?

Comment: Yes it does require a password.

Comment: How are you handling that requirement in your cron job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create a systemd unit.
All the possible options you can find here: [www.freedesktop.org/.../systemd.unit.html](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)
but I am going to present simple example:

1.Lets create a bash script which will write the date and time of each system bootup to the file: `/root/file`
Only `root` user has permissions to write and edit files in `/root` directory.
I am going to switch user to the `root` with `sudo su -`
Lets create a script `/root/timelog.sh` and make it executable `chmod +x /root/timelog.sh`

```
   #!/bin/bash

   if ! [ /root/file ]; then touch /root/file; fi 
   echo $(date) >> /root/file
```

2.Now we need the `System Unit` file: `/etc/systemd/system/timelog.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=timelog.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/timelog.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3.Last task is to make sure it will start with the system:

```
systemctl enable timelog
```

Comment: Genius! I never considered making it into a service. Of course! Thank you Romank!

Comment: @MarkDeven If this answered your question, would you select it as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Yes @RomanK, sorry for the delay in doing so. Christmas season and all.

Comment: the software is giving an error since the script requires an X display. Any ideas how to make it use the default :0 display? I tried `Environment=DISPLAY:0.0`.

Comment: @MarkDeven This question will fork significantly from the original question but check if [THIS](https://superuser.com/questions/759759/writing-a-service-that-depends-on-xorg) answers it.

Comment: It continued giving me issues but I was able to convince the development team to run it on a webserver since the gui used html anyways. Thanks for your help!